# How to loop and render elements in React after we got the data from the backend?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, loops, jsx

How is it possible to loop through the data from the backend and render components based on it?

I've tried something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import BuildingItem from './components/buildingItem';
import { Config } from './config/config';

export default function Buildings() {

  const buildings = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(Config.domain + 'kingdom/buildings', {
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          buildings.push(<BuildingItem type={data[i].type} level={data[i].level} />);
        }
      })
  })

  return (
    <div className='buildings'>
      <div className='buildings-container'>
        {buildings}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And also tried something like this when returning

```
<div className='buildings-container'>
        {buildings.map((item)=> (
              item
        )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of state here and then map through that.

instead of this:

```
 .then(data => {
        
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          buildings.push(<BuildingItem type={data[i].type} level={data[i].level} />);
        }
      })
```

use React.useState,  for example: `const [data, setData] = useState()` instead of `const buildings = [];`

```
 .then(data => {
       // create state like this for example: const [data, setData] = useState() instead of const buildings = [];
      setData(data)
  })
```

then in the jsx do something like this:

```
{
data.map((item, idx) => <BuildingItem type={item.type} level={item.level} />)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to change something like this. The thing is pushing item to the `const buildings = []` has no effect. So you need to use `useState` hook

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import BuildingItem from './components/buildingItem';
import { Config } from './config/config';

export default function Buildings() {

  const [buildings, setBuildings] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(Config.domain + 'kingdom/buildings', {
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setBuildings(data))
  })

  return (
    <div className='buildings'>
      <div className='buildings-container'>
        {buildings.map((item)=> (
          <BuildingItem type={item.type} level={item.level} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```